# How to split an expression with diffrent time part?

Tags: c#, regex

There is a string expression, I need split them to different part then I can do some datetime function to get a new datetime.

```
var expression = "2M15D20H4m";
//Y--year
//M--month
//D--days
//H--hours
//m--minutes
//s--seconds
//the new datetime should be:
var newDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).AddDays(15).AddHours(20).AddMinutes(4);
```

Any suggestion on this? Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to achieve and the code where you got stuck?

Comment: I think I can get a general function to calculate the later expression of the new datatime rather than a fixed way to recognize the string.

Comment: Use the DateTime constuctor : DateTime now = DateTime.Now; DataTime newDate = new DataTime(now.Year, now.Months + 2, now.Days + 15, now.Hours + 20, now.Minutes + 4, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match your required fields :

```
[0-9]+M|[0-9]+D|[0-9]+H|[0-9]+m|
```

Comment: Thanks, This is the way, and it also include decimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `DateTime.ParseExact()` method:

```
string expression = "2M15D20H4m";
string dateFormat = "M'M'dd'D'HH'H'm'm'";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(expression, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Another example with the same `dateFormat`:

```
string expression2 = "12M15D20H44m";
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(expression2, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also parse string to `TimeSpan` (particularly when number of months is bigger than 12), but here is a problem with numbers of days. So you can try this, a little bit odd, approach:

```
string expression = "52M33D10H17m";
string timeSpanFormat = "dd'D'h'H'm'm'";

int indexOfM = expression.IndexOf("M");
string timeSpanExpr = new string(expression.Skip(indexOfM+1).ToArray());
int months = int.Parse(expression.Substring(0, indexOfM));           

TimeSpan timeSpan= TimeSpan.ParseExact(timeSpanExpr, timeSpanFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Add(timeSpan).AddMonths(months);
```

Comment: The variable in the string can be over than the normal interger number. There is an error when: string expression2 = "14M45D20H44m";